# SSIS Ingres 32-bit ODBC source, SQL Server 2014 64-bit destination issue

Tags: ssis, odbc, sql-server-2014

I know similar questions have been asked before...

I am working on a remediation project which requires to migrate an existing SSIS package from SQL Server 2008 32-bits to 2014 64 bits. The data source is an Ingres database (32-bit server, 2 tables). Some CRUD statements are performed in SSIS because updates a couple of tables on the SQL Server side.

It works beautifully on the previous platforms but with the SQL Server upgrade to 2014-64 bit it does not work anymore, with the famous error

> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

I have tried to set the "Run64bitRunTime" flag in the SSIS package to false, but then the OLEDB driver on SQL Server 2014 complains

> An OLE DB error has occurred.... An OLE DB record is available.The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager “” failed...

Out of curiosity when I tried to use the SQL Server Import and Export 32-bits program I can communicate with both Ingres and SQL Server 2014 and transfer data across from Ingres to SQL with no problem. I can save the Import-and-Export into a package but I really don't want to add all the SQL transformation statements from the original package to the new one (consider it is a remediation project).

I am now confused why the new package fails, but the Import and Export wizard works?  Is there something I need to change in the new package to make it works in the new environment (apart from altering the Run64bitRunTime flag)

More information: I have tried to install the SSIS package as a file, or as part of the Integration Services Catalog, but both fail.

Any more information required please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can confirm if this issue can be replicated by explicitly running the package on both 32 and 64 bit `DTExec` respectively using the command line? The database drivers might be the issue

Comment: [This article](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/MsSqlOn64bitWin) from [my employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/) may help you...  As may installing and configuring DSNs with both [32-bit and 64-bit drivers for Ingres](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-ingres/).

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem by editing the SSIS package to make the SQL server data source to become OLEDB. It was painful to remap all the data columns though.